# How to create a column for each year from a single date column containing year and month?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

If I have a Data

```
Date        Values
2005-01     10
2005-02     20
2005-03     30
2006-01     40
2006-02     50
2006-03     70
```

How can I change Year Column? like this

```
Date 2015 2016
 01   10   40
 02   20   50
 03   30   70
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df[['year','month']] = df.Date.str.split('-', expand=True)
df = df.pivot(index='month', columns='year', values='Values')
print (df)
year   2005  2006
month            
01       10    40
02       20    50
03       30    70
```